# Laravel tokenmismatch exception

Tags: laravel, token, csrf, csrf-protection

Every once in a while I get a token mismatch exception. I send the token so that can't be it. When I clear cache en delete my cookies it's fixed again. What could this be?

**Additional info**

It started happening when I cached all rendered html to make the website offline capable.

Comment: I think the problem is your token expire within some times . check your cookie store time limit

Answer (score 0):

The token mismatch exception indicates that your session has expired.

You can properly handle this exception. Take a look in [this forum](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/l5-properly-handle-tokenmismatchexception-when-logging-in).

Comment: Thanks =) this is very helpful, I'll definitely implement this

Answer (score 0):

you can increase the time limit of session in config/session.php

```
/*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
*/

'lifetime' => 30,

'expire_on_close' => true,
```

its 30 minutes by default..

Comment: Tried this, hope it works. Will report back if it works